# $\arg(zw)=\arg(z)+\arg(w)$ any one of $zw$, $z$, or $w$ outside of $(-\pi, \pi]$

Tags: complex-analysis

In [the solution of 3(b)](http://www.math.ubc.ca/%7Esjer/math300/solmt1.pdf), it states that the solution to $1+z^3 = 0$ is $-1, -w, -w^2 (w = -1/2 + \sqrt{3}i/2)$. However, I think it should be $-w^k, k \in \mathbb{N}$.

Take $k=3$ for example, then the equation is still true.

Comment: The problem is that if you allow $k \geq 3$, you get duplicate solutions (for example, $-1 = -w^{3}$). The solutions listed are the set of all *unique* solutions.

Comment: @JoshuaWang How is $-e^{2\pi i}$ same as $-1$?

Comment: Ah, I think I see it. Because $cos(2\pi) = 1$ and $sin(2\pi)  = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Well, yes, but there are only three solutions.  The additional solutions you found are repeats.